# docker-compose: how to get IP from corporate DHCP server

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, dhcp

I'm running a container with docker-compose from a Macbook Pro inside my company LAN, and the problem is that default IP and subnet assigned to the container are not "supported" in my company.

For instance right now I have a bridge network with subnet `172.21.0.0/16`, but I need it to be `172.26.0.0/16` (as on my MBP) to be compliant with my corporate DHCP server;
also, I need the container to **ask my DHCP server for the IP**, in order to avoid duplicates on the network. I can't use static IP.

Does anyone know how to configure it? Any help is appreciated.

Here's the setup:

- OS: Mac OS High Sierra
- Docker: Engine 17.12.0-ce Compose 1.18.0
- Base image: Ubuntu (https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if could try the link below could be useful on how you configure [4 ways to configure connection to docker](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/)

Comment: Hey :) I know your answer is 4 years old, but would you mind summarizing it here? SO is meant to be a Q&A site, not a link collection. Thanks & Cheers :)